# My submit button doesn't work and triggers an Ajax request instead

Tags: php, prestashop-1.6

I try to submit my form but no action happens and when I press the submit button, a green message at the top right saying setting update is displayed.
But I think there's something missing in my code but I can't figure out what it is that knows

here is my main file

```
<?php

require dirname(__FILE__) . '/controllers/admin/AdminMoreProduct.php';

if (!defined('_PS_VERSION_')) {
    exit;
}

class MoreProduct extends Module {

    public function __construct() {

        //description module
        $this->name = 'moreproduct';
        $this->tab = 'administration';
        $this->version = '1.0';
        $this->author = 'Thibaut';


        //enabled config
        $this->bootstrap = true;
        $this->need_instance = 0;
        //$this->controllers = array('moreProduct');

        //display
        parent::__construct();
        $this->displayName = $this->l("MoreProduct");
        $this->description = $this->l('add more product for product');

    }

    public function install() {

        $this->createDb();
        $this->installModuleTab();

        return parent::install() &&
        $this->registerHook('header') &&
        $this->registerHook('displayAdminProductsExtra') &&
        $this->registerHook('actionProductUpdate');

    }

    public function uninstall() {
        return $this->uninstallModuleTab() && parent::uninstall() && $this->removeDb();
    }

    public function installModuleTab() {
        $tab = new Tab();
        $langs = language::getLanguages();

        foreach($langs as $l) {
            $tab->name[$l['id_lang']] = "MoreProduct";
        }
        $tab->module = $this->name;
        $tab->id_parent = 0;
        $tab->active = 1;
        $tab->class_name = "AdminMoreProduct";

        if (!$tab->save()):
            return $this->_abortInstall($this->l('Unable to create the "Admin MoreProduct" tab'));
        endif;
    }

    public function uninstallModuleTab() {
        $idTab = Tab::getIdFromClassName('AdminMoreProduct');
        if($idTab) {
            $tab = new Tab($idTab);
            return $tab->delete();
        }
        return true;
    }

    //DB
    public function createDb() {
        $query = "
            create table ps_moreproduct (
                id int(3) not null auto_increment,
                text_mp varchar(100),
                url_img varchar(100),
                url_puce varchar(100),
                id_product int(10) UNSIGNED,
                primary key(id),
                foreign key (id_product) references ps_product(id_product)
            );
        ";

        return Db::getInstance()->query($query);
    }

    public function removeDb() {

        $query = 'DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ' . _DB_PREFIX_ . 'moreproduct;'; 

        return Db::getInstance()->query($query);
    }
    //hook

    public function hookDisplayAdminProductsExtra($params) {

        $form = new AdminMoreProductController();

        if(isset($params['id_product']) && (int)$params['id_product']) {
            $product = Db::getInstance()->ExecuteS(' select text_mp, url_img, url_puce, id_product 
                                                     from ' . _DB_PREFIX_ .'moreproduct 
                                                     where id_product = ' . $params['id_product'] . ';');

            $this->context->smarty->assign(array(
                "product" => $product,
                "form" => $form->renderForm(),
                "bt" => $form->postProcess()
            ));
        }

        return $this->display(__FILE__ , 'views/templates/admin/moreProduct.tpl');
    }

    public function hookActionProductUpdate($params) {

    }

    public function hookHeader() {}
}
```

My controller file :

```
<?php

require _PS_MODULE_DIR_.'moreproduct/classes/MoreProductTabClass.php';

class AdminMoreProductController extends ModuleAdminController {

    public function __construct() {
        $this->bootstrap = true;
        $this->allow_export = true;
        $this->table = 'MoreProduct';
        $this->className = 'MoreProductTabClass';

        parent::__construct();

        $this->fields_list = array(
            'id' => array(
                'title' => $this->l('ID of more product'),
                'align' => 'center',
                'havingFilter' => true,
            ),
            'text_mp' => array(
                'title' => $this->l('text of product'),
                'align' => 'center',
                'havingFilter' => true,
            ),
            'url_img' => array(
                'title' => $this->l('image more product'),
                'search' => false,
                'align' => 'center',
                'display_image' => true,
                'prefix' => "<img src='../modules/moreproduct/img/",
                'suffix' => "' width='100'>",
                'havingFilter' => true,
            ),
            'url_puce' => array(
                'title' => $this->l('puce more product'),
                'search' => false,
                'align' => 'center',
                'display_image' => true,
                'prefix' => "<img src='../modules/ed_label_product/img/puce",
                'suffix' => "' width='100'>",
                'havingFilter' => true,
            ),
        );
    }

    public function init() {
        parent::init();
    }

    public function postProcess(){

        $msg = "";

        if(Tools::isSubmit('submitSendData')) {
             /*$tab = new MoreProductTabClass();
            $tab->text_mp = Tools::getValue('text_mp');
            $tab->url_img = Tools::getValue('url_img');
            $tab->url_puce = Tools::getValue('url_puce');
            $tab->id_product = Tools::getValue('id');


            if(isset($_FILES['url_img'])) {
                $tab->url_img = $this->checkImg($_FILES['url_img'], '../modules/moreproduct/img/');
            } else if(isset($obj->url_img)) {
                $obj->url_img = $tab->url_img;
            } else {
                $tab->url_img = null;
            }

            //SQL
            $sql = "insert into ps_moreproduct (text_mp, url_img, url_puce, id_product) 
                    values ('" . $tab->text_mp . "' , '" . $tab->url_img . "' , '" . $tab->url_puce . "' , " . $tab->id_product . "); ";

            $tab->save();*/
            $msg = "submit button";

        }
        return $msg;
    }

    public function renderForm() {

        $this->initToolbar();
        $obj = $this->loadObject(true);

        $this->addJquery();
        $this->addjQueryPlugin(array('scrollTo', 'alerts', 'chosen', 'autosize', 'fancybox', 'select2' ));
        $this->context->controller->addJS(_MODULE_DIR_.'/moreproduct/views/js/moreproduct.js');

        $options = array(
            array(
              'id_option' => 1,                 // The value of the 'value' attribute of the <option> tag.
              'name' => 'test1',
              'value' => 'test1'
            ),
            array(
              'id_option' => 2,
              'name' => 'test2',
              'value' => 'test1'
            ),
        );

        $this->fields_form = array(
            'legend' => array(
                'title' => $this->l('button more product'),
                'icon' => 'icon-globe'
            ),
            'input' => array(
                array(
                    'type' => 'text',
                    'class' => 'col-lg-6',
                    'id' => 'text_mp',
                    'name' =>'text_mp',
                ),
                array(
                    'type' => 'file',
                    'class' => 'col-lg-6',
                    'id' => 'url_img',
                    'name' =>'url_img',
                    'display_image' => true,
                ),
                array(
                    'type' => 'select',            
                    'name' => 'url_puce',                               
                    'options' => array(
                      'query' => $options,                           
                      'id' => 'id_option',                          
                      'name' => 'name'                               
                    )
                ),

            ),

            'submit' => array(
                'title' => $this->module->l('Send Data'),
                'name' => 'submitSendData',
                'id' => 'submitSendData',
                'class' => 'btn btn-primary',
            ),

        );

        $helper = new HelperForm();
        return parent::renderForm();
    }

    public function checkImg(String $img,String $destination) {
        $newName = false;
        $allowed = array('image/gif', 'image/jpeg', 'image/jpg', 'image/png');
        $tmpFile = $_FILES[$img]['tmp_name'];
        $nameFile = $_FILES[$img]['name'];

        if (!empty($img)) {
            if(!is_uploaded_file($tmpFile) ) {
                exit("Le fichier est introuvable");
            }

            if(in_array($img['type'], $allowed)) {
                $newName = md5($img['name'] . time()) . "." . explode("/", $img['type'])[1];
                $path = $destination . $newName;

                if(!move_uploaded_file($tmpFile, $path) ) {
                    exit("Impossible de copier le fichier dans " . $destination);
                }
            } else {
                exit("Le fichier n'est pas une image");
            } 
        }
        return $newName;
    }  
}
```

my view :

```
{$bt|@var_dump}

<FORM action="" method="post">
  {$form}
</FORM>


<HR>
<TABLE class="table">
  <THEAD>
    <TR>
      <TH scope="col">content</TH>
      <TH scope="col">image</TH>
      <TH scope="col">icon used</TH>
    </TR>
  </THEAD>
  <TBODY>
    {if count($product) > 0}
        {foreach from=$product item=p}
            <TR>
                <TD>{ $p['text_mp'] }</TD>
                <TD><IMG src="/modules/moreproduct/img/{$p['url_img']}" alt=""></TD>
                <TD><IMG src="/modules/moreproduct/img/{$p['url_puce']}" alt=""></TD>
            </TR>
        {/foreach}
    {else}
        <DIV class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
                not data on table moreproduct
        </DIV>   
    {/if}
  </TBODY>
</TABLE>
```

Please help me, I'm not an expert in prestashop and I don't know all the tricks of the CMS yet.then it's been a day since I've been on it

Comment: FYI, you don't need to write your HTML in capitals. It's standard to write it in lowercase.

Comment: @Script47 psst, he's using FrontPage ;)

Comment: How do I submit my button to the BO then?